# How to get bootstrap3 accordion to scroll smoothly to top of browser?

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to get this to work smoothly, problem is that when the accordion panel is clicked, it seems to just "jump" to the top of the screen without scrolling.

The salon page scrolling bit works perfectly

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // staff page scrolling     
    $('a.staff').click(function(){

        //$("html, body").scrollTop($(this).position().top);

        var el = $(this).attr('href');

        var elWrapped = $(el);

        scrollToDiv(elWrapped,50);

        return false;

    });


    // salon page scrolling 
    $('li.subnav a').click(function(){

        // set active states
        var parent = $(this).parent();

        siblings = parent.siblings(),

        isOn = parent.toggleClass('active').hasClass('active');

        siblings.toggleClass('active', !isOn);

        // get element and offset
        var el = $(this).attr('href');

        var elWrapped = $(el);

        scrollToDiv(elWrapped,175);

        return false;

    });

    // scroll to accordion element 
    function scrollToDiv(element,navheight){

        var offset = element.offset();

        var offsetTop = offset.top;

        var totalScroll = offsetTop-navheight;

        $('body,html').animate({

                scrollTop: totalScroll

        }, 800);

    }

});
```

And here is the panel it is supposed to be sliding

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-data-parent-001, #accordion-data-parent-002" href="#collapse-[[+id]]" class="staff">
      <div class="panel-heading" >
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-3">[[+tv.headshot]]</div>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">[[+pagetitle]]</h4>
                  <p>[[+introtext]]</p>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </a>
  <div id="collapse-[[+id]]" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">[[+content]]</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?